# how to create add user to linux machine with perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I've searched for some hint about this one but I'm  clueless

I'm trying to add a user to a linux machine with perl
code :

```
my $md5password = `openssl passwd -1 $password1`;
system("useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/$username -p $md5password");
```

but this is resulted in :
`sh: 2: -p: not found`

when I'm executing this commands via terminal there's no problem...
arrr!
anyone?

update:

10x to @BraveNewCurrency advice it work's :)

code:

```
if(($password1 eq $password2) && length($password1) > 0)
{
    $valid = 1;
    my $md5password = `openssl passwd -1 $password1`;
    chomp($md5password);
    system("useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/$username -p \'$md5password\' $username");
```

I will look more into sanitizing `$username` later on.

I cant upvote @BraveNewCurrency cause my rep is under 15 ...I will be glad if some of you will upvote him.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to sanitize `$username` - you've got a newline and/or a semicolon in it (guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking your username/password for shell meta characters, and escaping them. (Otherwise it's a security problem waiting to happen.)

You should also look into Chef/Puppet/Salt/Ansible/.. or the like, which allow you to automate building servers at a much higher level. They are all declarative (and idempotent) so don't worry about icky details.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command uses a list of arguments, not a string.
you should also probably be explicit regarding the path to the command you are trying to execute.

Have you tried:

```
@args = (  
          '/usr/sbin/useradd', 
          '-s', '/bin/bash', 
          '-d', "/home/$username", 
          '-p', $md5password
         );
system(@args) == 0
    or die "Failed adding user: @args failed: $?"
```

As others have said, you should make sure you sanitize the `$username` before you create the user or you could get in big trouble.